# When will the elections end, and Will they publish the results?

Tags: support, election

What's the status on the SO moderator elections?

According to the [**blog**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/02/stack-overflow-2010-moderator-election-begins/), the election was planned to take one week.

Are there any plans on when the results will be published? *Will* the results be published, or just who the new moderator is?

Or did I overlook a big election thread?

Comment: They're still rigging the votes, which takes some time to appear fair.

Comment: If the election is already over, then I didn't win. That's all I know. (Not that it would surprise me.)

Comment: You wuz robbed @mmyers!

Comment: Looks like I finished fourth, if I read the files right. There were a lot of people who voted for Jason Cohen and didn't pick a second or third choice.

Comment: @mmyers I think we ought to demand a recount ;) Hehe.

Comment: Actually, I didn't read the files right. I was fifth. Guess I'll tell my lawyer to drop the Supreme Court appeal now. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/02/stack-overflow-2010-moderator-election-results/

Comment: No Dartboard? Boooooooooo!

Comment: Huzzah!  Thanks for releasing the actual vote counts!

Comment: +1 If I'm reading that correctly, I came in third. Awesome! Do I get a cheap disposable ribbon? :)

Comment: Full transparency FTW! Thanks.

Comment: @jonathan, you will always be #3 in my heart..

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Comforting :)

Answer (score 3):

They printed out the User Voting page and are throwing darts at it.

Too bad none of them have good aim. We can expect one to hit the paper by Wednesday.

Then we will know who will become the next Moderator.

Comment: Sweet, then I might have a chance after all...

Comment: Love the throwing darts comment. An easy solution to difficult problems...

Comment: by Wensday? At first sight, I thought it's a pun for "when's-the-day?" :P